# Three.js ShaderMaterial shaders: What's the identity ("hello world") vertex and fragment code?

Tags: three.js, glsl, light, shadows

I'm trying to write a custom shader for THREE.js shadows, but am new to GLSL and having some trouble getting started. I think the best approach is to start with the "identity" functions that produce the same shading as a default `ShaderMaterial` function and the slowly hack on those. But I can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
      // vertex function
      void main() {
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1 ); 
      }

      // fragment function
      uniform vec3 shadowColor;
      void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(shadowColor, 1);
      }
```

The `uniforms` just provides black as the shadow color:

```
       uniforms: {
          shadowColor: {
                type: 'c',
                value: new THREE.Color(0x000000)
          }
        },
        vertexShader: vshader,
        fragmentShader: fshader,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
        transparent: true
    });
```

This produces nothing in the way of a shadow, though it's firing correctly, I see, because I can change the output of `gl_FragColor` to an arbitrary HSL value and see the whole view shaded with that color. Clearly I don't understand the correct `vertexShader` that produces the same output as the default.

Any help with an identity vertexShader and fragmentShader would really aid me in getting my feet wet with GLSL.

Thanks!

Comment: **1)** Create a `ShaderMaterial` (`var sm = new THREE.ShaderMaterial();`), then look at `sm.vertexShader` and `sm.fragmentShader`. There's your "hello world"/"identity." The code provided draws everything in flat red. **2)** Dig into the three.js code and look for `ShaderLib`. Follow the bread crumbs, and you'll find values like `meshlambert_frag`/`meshlambert_vert` and `shadowmap_pars_fragment`/`shadowmap_pars_vertex` which are code chunks used to build the common shaders, like `MeshLambertMaterial`.

Comment: Take a look at the ship load of examples [HERE](http://2pha.com/blog/experimenting-threejs-shaders-and-shadermaterial/)

Comment: Pulled the defaults from the ShaderMaterial object liked suggested -- thanks!